# How can I get the name of the database a DBExpress TSqlConnection is actually connected to?

Tags: delphi, firebird, dbexpress, delphi-6

I'm testing a quite old Delphi 6 application and would like to display the database name the TSqlConnection is actually connected to, so I can see quickly if I'm connected to the test or production database.

In sqlconnections.ini, the app has a connection named 'Vienna' to a Firebird database defined like this:
Database=192.168.1.15:ProductionDB (it's an alias)
and I've replaced that for testing purposes with
Database=192.168.1.15:TestDB.

But I've seen that just accessing the TSqlConnection's Params-List and there the value of 'Database' does not work. This value is always set the same as it is in design mode.

How can I find out which database (which Firebird alias in my case) the TSqlConnection is actually connected to?

Comment: Which Firebird version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

monitoring tables were introduced into FB 2.1.x :-)

So try

```
 select MON$DATABASE_NAME from MON$DATABASE
```

Or try

```
 select MON$ATTACHMENT_NAME from MON$ATTACHMENTS
    where MON$ATTACHMENT_ID = CURRENT_CONNECTION
```

See info at

- c:\Program Files (x86)\Firebird\Firebird_2_1\doc\README.monitoring_tables.txt
- http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=mon_database via www.translate.ru
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29919/firebird-monitoring-tables
- http://www.upscene.com/documentation/fbtm2/index.html?dm_monitoringtables.htm
- http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/community/conference-2014/pcisar/#1

Answer (score 0):

When `SQLConnection.Params` property is empty `Params.Values['Database']` return empty string even when `BeforeConnect` or `AfterConnect` events is fired .

You can use TSQLConnection.OnLogin event.
For example :

```
procedure TForm11.SQLConnection1Login(Database: TSQLConnection;
  LoginParams: TWideStrings);
var
 i : integer;
begin
  //Show all params
  for I := 0 to LoginParams.Count - 1 do
    ShowMessage(LoginParams[i]);

  // Show database
  ShowMessage(LoginParams.Values['Database']);   
end;
```

> Use the OnLogin event to assign values to the User_Name, Password, and
>   Database parameters immediately before TSQLConnection attempts to
>   connect to the database server. OnLogin only occurs if the LoginPrompt
>   property is true. If LoginPrompt is true but there is no OnLogin event
>   handler, a default login dialog appears in which the user can enter a
>   user name and password. The connection fails if correct values for the
>   user name and password are not supplied in the dialog or by the
>   OnLogin event handler.

[Source](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLConnection.OnLogin)