# Exception when 'SELECT * FROM ....' with Delphi XE-8 and FIREBIRD local database

Tags: string, delphi, utf-8, firebird, delphi-xe8

It raises an exception: every time a Delphi XE-8 program executes this code:

```
procedure TForm_hora_edit_.SpdBtn_KOMISII_ZASEDANIA_Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Data_Module.IBQuery_KOMISII_ZASEDANIA_.Active := False;
  Data_Module.IBQuery_KOMISII_ZASEDANIA_.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM KOMISII_ZASEDANIA ORDER BY ZASED_DT DESC';
  Data_Module.IBQuery_KOMISII_ZASEDANIA_.Active := True;  
end;
```

The exception is raised on this line:

```
Data_Module.IBQuery_KOMISII_ZASEDANIA_.Active := True;
```

Exception message:

> No mapping for the Unicode character exits in the target multi-byte
>   code page

I did create the table KOMISII_ZASEDANIA using a free software: SQL Manager Lite for IB/FB

The charset of the database is: UTF8; the table contains characters from the Cyrillic alphabet.

I need to avoid the above exception.

Comment: Show me the properties of the TDataSet component you use to connect. Most probably you forgot to set connection charset

Comment: Find "lc_type" at http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/ibx.htm and see forum at sql.ru

Comment: The component I use is: TIBQuery, it does not contain any property connection charset, ( and nothing similar to charset ).

Comment: try checking your database through https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBExpert // in after registering the database in that IDE - try three experiments: close the database, in registered properties set Connection Charset to { 1: NONE; 2: WIN1251; 3:UTF-8 }, open database, try to do your query if it would show the data or fail.

Also I suggest you to check database and tables are in UTF-8, not in UNICODE_FSS

Comment: TIBQuery dows not float in the air - you connect it to the some DataBase component which should have correct connection parameters, including connection charset

Comment: did you create TField components for the query in design-time or are them autocreated in runtime? There are different TField-derived classes for AnsiString and UnicodeString/WideString.  Typical gotcha is that even TWideString-type Field has non-Unicode .AsString property

Comment: FBConnection.Params.Values['lc_ctype']  := 'UTF8'; The TField components for the TIBQuery are autocreated at Runtime.

Comment: FBConnection.Params.Values['lc_ctype'] := 'WIN1251'; Does not raise any Exception activatng above TIBQuery.

Comment: check the correct charsets with `IBExpert `- there is combo-box with them

there may be "UTF-8" identifier rather than "UTF8" or anything other pecularity

Comment: OTOH if you only use Cyrillics then 1251 connection is perfectly enough for you

Comment: Maybe IBX - or client DLL from Interbase - just works badly with Firebird.

Comment: This is a common beginner error, comes from not specifying the charset when connecting using IBX via firebird connection string.

Comment: @WarrenP that was my first guess, but then he said above in comments that "FBConnection.Params.Values['lc_ctype'] := 'UTF8'"

Comment: My last opinion is that the free software: SQL Manager Lite for IB/FB contains a bug, which destroys the Charset of the fields during altering teir tables. I saw how after I added an UTF-8 field to a Primary key of the table, the content of that field was changed terrible to unreadable for me characters. So I stop to use: SQL Manager Lite for IB/FB and start to use: IBExpert - free for Cyrillic alphabet users ! I hope my Database is not corrupted because of using the: SQL Manager Lite for IB/FB.

Comment: using IBExpert make dump of the database metadata aka scheme aka structure into text script and see if all the tables/columns have correct chrasets/collations - and check sql.ru/forum/interbase

Comment: check via FB2 monitor tables, maybe `SQL Manager Lite` forgets to set charset to the collection it makes? maybe it connects with lc_type=NONE ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939006

Comment: It's also possible that the underlying database is not encoded in UTF8, even though he has specified that in the connection string.

Answer (score 1):

The error shown is not an error of Firebird, it is likely an error of Delphi when it receives the bytes of the field and interprets them in UTF-8. Based on the comments and the description of the problem, it looks like the field is probably `CHARACTER SET NONE`, and the current content is likely in `WIN1251` (or another single byte encoding), not `UTF-8`; having a character set `NONE` means Firebird cannot convert it to the target connection encoding and sends it as is, leaving it up to the client application to interpret it.

Make sure the field has a character set other than `NONE` or `OCTETS` and convert the current content as needed.

Comment: ...or IBX finally lost compatibility with later Firebird